# Wordpress add_rewrite_rule multiple page don't work

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to add multiple rewrite rule but I don't get this to work. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
add_action('init', function() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^report/([^/]*)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=report', 'top');
});

add_action('init', function() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^sector/([^/]*)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=sector', 'top');
});

add_action('init', function() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^([^/]*)/?$', 'index.php', 'top');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was routing to only "index.php" in the last rule. I did add a page there so my code that works looks like this:

```
add_action('init', function() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^app/([^/]*)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=app', 'top');
});

add_action('init', function() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^account/([^/]*)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=account', 'top');
});

add_action('init', function() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^/([^/]*)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=site', 'top');
});
```

Remember also to add this role is right order, because the order do matter.